# How to set permission on a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have an "Announcement List" in SharePoint 2013 & I have 3 users namely "contentreader", "contenteditor" and "contentapprover". **All these users have "Read" permission in the site.**

**My requirement is:-** 1) I want to give **"Read"** permission to user **"contentreader"** on **"Announcement List"**

2) I want to give **"Edit"** permission to user **"contenteditor"** on **"Announcement List"**

3) I want to give **"Approve"** permission to user **"contentapprover"** on **"Announcement List"**

All this should be done, **without changing their main permission level, which is "Read".** I have read many articles but could not understand. Please kindly suggest me how this can be achieved. Your time and help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop inheriting permissions on that list first.
Then, you should be able to add those users directly to that list with whatever permissions you need.

Comment: Thank you napo for your quick response and explaination...did exactly what u have suggested and it is working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear! Anytime.